# Google Analytics 4 - wrong price displayed in the report

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I got some problems with GA4 using Wordpress Woocommerce website. The last 1-1.5 month i have got sometimes an incorrect price of the purchased products.
For example, the item cost is 395 euro, but GA4 was display 394.56 euro. It's happened from time to time. The Woocommerce orders have correct price, but not GA4. It's happened from time to time.

Anybody know what is may the problem?
[Google Analytics 4 report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz2Ng.png)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who lands here in the future as well as me, this question is answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74808430/5025571

> According to
> https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9796179?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article
>
> Even if the currency setting for your property or view is set to match
> your local currency, Analytics performs a conversion at the moment of
> processing a hit for non-USD currencies and a fresh conversion on that
> figure each time a report is generated. This can lead to very small
> differences in your reports for your local currency due to
> fluctuations in the daily exchange rate.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same problem, at first, I thought it was due to currency change but even when I changed analytics currency the problem is there from time to time and the gap is really big sometimes.

Would Appreciate it if someone can explain how this is produced and a solution for it.